# Dragging and dropping from SharePoint into another software

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Does anyone know if I can drag and drop from SharePoint into another upload space on a browser software? i.e. EstimateOne

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, due to the privacy of SharePoint, the operation is currently not possible.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? 

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.